# sql query: retrieve the distinct CODE where the MAKE = 'some value'

Tags: sql

I am looking for some help in creating the correct SQL for this scenario...

Two table Model and Serials simplified

```
Model
-----
CODE | MAKE | MODEL

Serials
-------
CODE (FK) | SERIAL
```

I want to retrieve the CODE, MAKE AND SERIAL where the MAKE = 'some value'
I only want the distinct CODES though...

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct code, make, model from model inner join code on model.code = serials.code where model = 'some value';
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's what you mean, but have you tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT code, make, serial
FROM model, serials
WHERE model.code = serials.code
AND make = 'some value'
```

Answer (score 1):

The way your tables seem to be set up there will be multiple rows in Serials for each Code, no? If so, there is no way to get ***all*** the serials for a single code without getting multiple rows for that code.  Is that what you meant by only getting distinct codes? If so, you can't do that... but otherwise...

```
try this:

Select Code, Make, Serial
From Model M
  Join Serials S
     On  M.code = S.code
Where Make = 'some value'
```

Comment: There are many entries for the same CODE with different SERIALS. I just want all the distinct codes with like a sample SERIAL i'm not concerned about what SERIAL is returned

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct Model.Code 
from Model JOIN Serials on Model.Code = Serials.Code 
where make = 'some value' and Serials.Serial not null
```

Edit after reading comment on other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming code is a `PRIMARY KEY` (otherwise, you cannot make an `FK` you mentioned):

```
SELECT  code, make,
        (
        SELECT  serial
        FROM    serials
        WHERE   serials.code = model.code
        LIMIT 1
        )
FROM    model
WHERE   MAKE = 'some value'
```

This is `MySQL` syntax.

You need to define which serial you want to show when you have several serials for a `code` and add an `ORDER BY` clause into subquery.

If you have this data:

```
code  make         model
123   SOME VALUE   Ford Sierra

code  serial
123   1
123   2
```

, do you want to show serial `1` or `2` and why?

Comment: i'll try this. it doesn't matter what serial is returned I just need to check the last few digits of the serial for each code